# Melting a DataFrame across multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame like this, with columns A, B, C and D and an index with date ranges represented as strings:

```
index                         A          B            C           D
03/05/2020-09/05/2020         0.000      3456.000     123.254     0.000              
26/04/2020-02/05/2020         0.000      123.123      555.255     0.000
19/04/2020-25/04/2020         9.253      0.000        223.1310    0.000
```

How do I melt it into this format, with the date range strings grouped as the index and the VALUE and ITEMS as columns?

```
DATE                       VALUE      ITEM    
03/05/2020-09/05/2020      0.000      A     
03/05/2020-09/05/2020      3456.000   B
03/05/2020-09/05/2020      123.254    C
03/05/2020-09/05/2020      0.000      D
26/04/2020-02/05/2020      0.000      A
26/04/2020-02/05/2020      123.123    B
26/04/2020-02/05/2020      555.255    C
26/04/2020-02/05/2020      0.000      D
19/04/2020-25/04/2020      9.253      A
19/04/2020-25/04/2020      0.000      B
19/04/2020-25/04/2020      223.1310   C
19/04/2020-25/04/2020      0.000      D
```

Comment: Is there an actual issue? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic], and provide a [mcve] as well as the current output.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you

```
df.unstack().reset_index(level = 0).sort_values('index')
```

...and rename or re-order columns and rows as needed.

```
df.unstack().reset_index(level = 0).sort_values('index').rename({'level_0':'ITEM',0:'VALUE'}, axis = 1)[['VALUE','ITEM']].merge(df.reset_index()['index'], how = 'inner', right_on = 'index', left_index = True).sort_index().set_index('index').rename_axis(index = 'DATE')
```

Result matches your example.

```
                          VALUE ITEM
DATE
03/05/2020-09/05/2020     0.000    A
03/05/2020-09/05/2020  3456.000    B
03/05/2020-09/05/2020   123.254    C
03/05/2020-09/05/2020     0.000    D
26/04/2020-02/05/2020     0.000    A
26/04/2020-02/05/2020   123.123    B
26/04/2020-02/05/2020   555.255    C
26/04/2020-02/05/2020     0.000    D
19/04/2020-25/04/2020     9.253    A
19/04/2020-25/04/2020     0.000    B
19/04/2020-25/04/2020   223.131    C
19/04/2020-25/04/2020     0.000    D
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately this doesn't produce the output format above.

Comment: If you re-order and rename, you'll get the same df you had above. E.g.:

df.unstack().reset_index(level = 0).sort_values('index').rename({'level_0':'ITEM',0:'VALUE'}, axis = 1)[['VALUE','ITEM']].merge(df.reset_index()['index'], how = 'inner', right_on = 'index', left_index = True).sort_index().set_index('index').rename_axis(index = 'DATE') I edited the original answer to show you there